# Visual Studio Code's Zen coding HTML comment

Tags: visual-studio-code, web-essentials, vscode-snippets, zen

In Visual Studio Code, is there a way to insert an HTML comment, like

```
<!-- something here -->
```

just like you can insert a div tag with a class of "foo" by doing:

```
div.foo + [TAB]
```

That results in

```
<div class="foo"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest versions the 'c' character is transformed into a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. cc:ie and cc:noie are the closest I know of for comments but this is not what you want.